# How Do i make image border animation like this website with a image

Tags: html, css

I want to make something like this: http://kizi.com/

Like in this website when you hover over a game icon it pops up a text with background and I also like the border animation.

```css
#games img {
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #ffd700;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#games img:hover {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="Games">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/110x100" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your css classes should `#Games` instead of `#games`

Comment: I want to make code my images as in the website i mentioned.

Comment: @NiK648 — Those are *selectors*, not classes.